# Нахождение чётных / нечётных чисел в строке(string)

Tags: c#, строки, if, for

Задача: Из представленных в строке numbers чисел найти одно отличающееся от всех число по чётности.

Строка выглядит таким образом: "1 2 2" или "2 4 7 8 10"

!Одно из важных условий: Счёт индексов чисел должен начинаться с 1 (не с 0, как мы знаем)!

(если данный момент не понятен - попробую объяснить по-лучше)

Я написал следующий код:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class IQ
{
    public static int Test(string numbers)
    { 
        int leng = numbers.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < leng; i++)
        {
            if ((Convert.ToInt32(numbers[i]) % 2) > 0)
            {
                return i;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Переменная leng принимает значение длины строки `numbers` (длина может быть любой)

Внутрь цикла `for` внедрил проверку условия на нечётность (конкретно в моей задаче надо находить нечётные числа, но это не помешает переконвертировать решение для нахождения чётных чисел)

Мне не удалось придумать, как мне вывести идентификатор нужного числа в человеческом виде, поэтому оставил просто возвращение идентификатора, чтобы убедиться, что основа программы раотает. Однако, к моему удивлению никакие значений не возвращаются.

Что я сделал не так, и как реализовать фичу с "человеческим счётом"(если непонятно я попробую обхяснить по-подробнее)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public static int Test(string numbers)
    { 
      var parts = numbers.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
      int iLastEven = -1;
      int iLastOdd = -1; 
      int countEven = 0;  
      int countOdd = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length && (countEven < 2 || countOdd < 2); i++)
      {
        var num = int.Parse(parts[i]);
        if (num % 2 == 0) 
        {
          iLastEven = i;
          countEven++;
        }
        else
        {
          iLastOdd = i;
          countOdd++;
        }
      } 
      if (countEven == 1 && countOdd > 1) 
        return iLastEven + 1;
      else if (countOdd == 1 && countEven > 1) 
        return iLastOdd + 1;
      else
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо! Единственное - исправте в последнем блоке if-else (в самом низу) переменну iLastEvent на iLastEven - как вы её инициализировали ранее.
Просто - это единственная ошибка, а поправка с моей стороны должна соднржать не менее 6 символов, по правилам сайта.